# Fade-in and Fade-out animation methods with pure javaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, fadein, fadeout

Summary : The summary of the problem is that I want to find out the complicated code corresponding to this easy code that we are executing in  jQuery. The code that I am referring to is that related to Fade-in and Fade-out animation methods used by  jQuery. I want to use pure javaScript code instead of jQuery .

This is the code used in jQuery and I want an equivalent pure javaScript code for it.

The following code will be clear to you, but excuse me, I want to point out more than one point,

*First point : which is that there is only one button to execute the function (i.e. Fade methods "in or out" for both conditions) .

*Second point : div is a container tag which has a class ="msg" but it has no text inside (i.e. in html ) and the text executed as soon as the function begins (i.e. in JavaScript ).

[image]

```
<body>

     <form autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
        <button type="button" id="btn">OK</button>
     </form>
     <div class="msg"></div>

     <script>
           $(document).ready(function (){

$('#btn').click(function (){
     let usName = $('#username').val();
     
     if(usName != ''){
        $('.msg').html('Welcome ' + usName);
        $('.msg').fadeIn(1500);
     }else{
        $('.msg').html('Username is required');
        $('.msg').fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
     }
                            });
                                        }); 
     </script>
     
</body>
```

what i have tried to do was very simple code which has not any dynamic animation methods, however that code has been executed well also.

```
<body>
   
    <form autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
        <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="show()">OK</button>
     </form>
     
     <div class="msg"></div>
    

     <script>
function show()

{    let usName = document.getElementById("username").value;

if (usName != "")
    { 
  document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0].innerHTML = "Welcome" +" "+ usName;
    }
else
{
  document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0].innerHTML = "Username is required";
}
  }
     </script>

</body>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnivF.jpg)

Comment: If I was you I would use CSS for the animation, and add a class that will trigger the animation that you can toggle with pure JavaScript. This don't need to be complicated code.

Comment: have a look to https://github.com/camsong/You-Dont-Need-jQuery

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Images](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are OK but aren't mandatory. Code as a [mcve] is required 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery website:

> The .fadeIn() method animates the opacity of the matched elements.

So write a css class with 0 opacity and a transition.

```
.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1500ms;
}
```

Now use simple JavaScript to apply the class to the element that you want to fade out and remove the class from the element you want to fade in.

```
document.getElementById('myId').classList.add('fade-out');
document.getElementById('myId').classList.remove('fade-out');
```

And if you want it to not affect your layout. You can set it to `display:none` immediately after the fade is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
.fade-in-out{
   opacity:0;
   transition: 1s;
}
```

You can use toggle to dynamically add or remove a class name

```js
document.querySelector('.my-element').classList.toggle('fade-in-out');
```